# How mongoose or mongoDB can separate and group my data?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I'm stunned. I can't find an exit in my problem. I've collection like a chat. It's like a private chat. So, I need to group messages by `userX` like:

```
{
    userA : [arrayOfMessages(my and to me)],
    userB: [arrayOfMessages(my and to me)]
}
```

**Sample Documents**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b98deac801df913ec53c173"),
    "group" : [],
    "isRead" : false,
    "recipient" : ObjectId("5b7175998a3b5705dc576e21"),
    "message" : "asfsaf",
    "sender" : ObjectId("5b69b678265fb633dc0ad165"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2018-09-12T09:38:52.412Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2018-09-12T09:38:52.412Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b98df18431f682808087518"),
    "group" : [],
    "isRead" : false,
    "recipient" : ObjectId("5b7175998a3b5705dc576e21"),
    "message" : "SMS to teacher",
    "sender" : ObjectId("5b69b678265fb633dc0ad165"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2018-09-12T09:40:40.353Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2018-09-12T09:40:40.353Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b98e83d98cd47182c0c4bfd"),
    "group" : [],
    "isRead" : false,
    "recipient" : ObjectId("5b7175998a3b5705dc576e21"),
    "message" : "SMS to teachersaf",
    "sender" : ObjectId("5b69b678265fb633dc0ad165"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2018-09-12T10:19:41.310Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2018-09-12T10:19:41.310Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b990c377c315523fc18cce2"),
    "isRead" : false,
    "recipient" : ObjectId("5b8cdbb6e5ae71ec32a8051c"),
    "message" : "1q",
    "sender" : ObjectId("5b7175998a3b5705dc576e21"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2018-09-12T12:53:11.214Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2018-09-12T12:53:11.214Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 5 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b990c457c315523fc18cce4"),
    "isRead" : false,
    "recipient" : ObjectId("5b8cdbb6e5ae71ec32a8051c"),
    "message" : "1qa",
    "sender" : ObjectId("5b7175998a3b5705dc576e21"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2018-09-12T12:53:25.205Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2018-09-12T12:53:25.205Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 6 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b990c4a7c315523fc18cce6"),
    "isRead" : false,
    "recipient" : ObjectId("5b8cdbb6e5ae71ec32a8051c"),
    "message" : "1qaz",
    "sender" : ObjectId("5b7175998a3b5705dc576e21"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2018-09-12T12:53:30.575Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2018-09-12T12:53:30.575Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 7 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b990c717c315523fc18cce8"),
    "isRead" : false,
    "recipient" : ObjectId("5b87cdfd3422340004b91ede"),
    "message" : "1q",
    "sender" : ObjectId("5b7175998a3b5705dc576e21"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2018-09-12T12:54:09.213Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2018-09-12T12:54:09.213Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 8 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b990c757c315523fc18ccea"),
    "isRead" : false,
    "recipient" : ObjectId("5b87cdfd3422340004b91ede"),
    "message" : "1qa",
    "sender" : ObjectId("5b7175998a3b5705dc576e21"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2018-09-12T12:54:13.274Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2018-09-12T12:54:13.274Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 9 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b990c787c315523fc18ccec"),
    "isRead" : false,
    "recipient" : ObjectId("5b87cdfd3422340004b91ede"),
    "message" : "1qaz",
    "sender" : ObjectId("5b7175998a3b5705dc576e21"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2018-09-12T12:54:16.491Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2018-09-12T12:54:16.491Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 10 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b990ca87c315523fc18ccee"),
    "isRead" : false,
    "recipient" : ObjectId("5b75858eff41da0d3c6480ab"),
    "message" : "1q",
    "sender" : ObjectId("5b7175998a3b5705dc576e21"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2018-09-12T12:55:04.620Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2018-09-12T12:55:04.620Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 11 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b990cac7c315523fc18ccf0"),
    "isRead" : false,
    "recipient" : ObjectId("5b75858eff41da0d3c6480ab"),
    "message" : "1qa",
    "sender" : ObjectId("5b7175998a3b5705dc576e21"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2018-09-12T12:55:08.678Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2018-09-12T12:55:08.678Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 12 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b990cb07c315523fc18ccf2"),
    "isRead" : false,
    "recipient" : ObjectId("5b75858eff41da0d3c6480ab"),
    "message" : "1qaz",
    "sender" : ObjectId("5b7175998a3b5705dc576e21"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2018-09-12T12:55:12.824Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2018-09-12T12:55:12.824Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 13 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b990d4c481c14080cc25d45"),
    "isRead" : false,
    "recipient" : ObjectId("5b69b678265fb633dc0ad165"),
    "message" : "adadaddasd",
    "sender" : ObjectId("5b7175998a3b5705dc576e21"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2018-09-12T12:57:48.426Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2018-09-12T12:57:48.426Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 14 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b990d53481c14080cc25d47"),
    "isRead" : false,
    "recipient" : ObjectId("5b69b678265fb633dc0ad165"),
    "message" : "adadaddasd asd a da",
    "sender" : ObjectId("5b7175998a3b5705dc576e21"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2018-09-12T12:57:55.369Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2018-09-12T12:57:55.369Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 15 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b990dcf481c14080cc25d4a"),
    "isRead" : false,
    "recipient" : ObjectId("5b7175998a3b5705dc576e21"),
    "message" : "!!!!!!!!!!!!!",
    "sender" : ObjectId("5b69b678265fb633dc0ad165"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2018-09-12T12:59:59.610Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2018-09-12T12:59:59.610Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 16 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b990dd1481c14080cc25d4c"),
    "isRead" : false,
    "recipient" : ObjectId("5b7175998a3b5705dc576e21"),
    "message" : "!!!!!!!!!!!!!",
    "sender" : ObjectId("5b69b678265fb633dc0ad165"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2018-09-12T13:00:01.679Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2018-09-12T13:00:01.679Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
```

I need a piece of advice. Maybe I should use aggregation but what does function of aggregation I should use?

Answer (score 0):

I usually use a couple functions cases:

- $bucket [Buckets documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/bucket/%20Buckets%20documentation)
- $group [Group documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/)

they are really handy to compute groups like the ones you need.
I think in your case $group is more suitable

Comment: Thank you. I'll try